# Scheduling 15 games into 5 rounds of 3 - random pick not working

Tags: ruby

I have an array of six players. This means I have fifteen unique games:

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

games = players.combination(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], 
#    [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]
```

I want to arrange these games randomly into 5 rounds of 3. Each player should play 1 game each round, and no pair should repeat from any previous round.

In each round, I have tried picking `player1` and `player2` randomly, using `while` loop coupled with `each`, but I always end up in infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: The downvote was because of the "what did you try" rule. You can't ask us to simply do your work for you, but if you have done your work, and encountered a problem, you can ask for help.

Comment: My downvote was because the text makes no sense to me. I have no idea what the OP is writing about.

Comment: @sawa, cryptic writing is a problem, too, but that can be deciphered with a bit of effort. I'm working out the answer, which will make it obvious what the asker  means =)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Since you have not posted it yet, I suppose in the end you couldn't get its meaning just like I couldn't.

Comment: I downvoted because I think my brain just melted. Question could be a health hazard.

Comment: It's a sumo basho with 6 wrestlers and 5 days.

Comment: The OP is likely hitting the problem that if you select pairings randomly from remaining possible, then the available pairs can be exhausted in rounds 2+.

Comment: I started coding it, I'm almost done, reopen it, apart from "what have you tried", the question actually does make sense.

Comment: @Casper, I confirm that the question is a health hazard, damage has been done to me.

Comment: @user3342732: I have tried to edit your question to improve the description of the problem. It is my best guess - please do edit back if I am wrong. In addition please add your current code, that is likely to get the question re-opened if SO users can see where you are going wrong rather than writing the whole answer for you. If it helps motivate you, I know the answer to this one, but cannot post while the question is closed :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, install `y_support` gem by typing `gem install y_support` in the command line. You know, I'm uncomfortable in Ruby without it. And then:

```
require 'y_support/all'

class Player
  include NameMagic

  def to_s; "#{name}" end
  def inspect; to_s end
end

Calvin, Paul, Willis, Shannon, Randy, Arnold = 6.times.map { Player.new }
Players = Player.instances

Bout = -> player1, player2, score_table do
  puts "Higashi, #{player1}! Nishi, #{player2}"
  winner = rand() > 0.5 ? player1 : player2
  puts "Winner: #{winner}!!!"
  puts
  score_table[ winner ] = score_table[ winner ] + 1
end

Basho = -> days: days do
  combinations = Players.shuffle.combination( 2 ).to_a
  first = days.times.map { combinations.shift }
  second = combinations.combination( days )
    .find { |c| first.zip( c ).all? { |a, b| ( a + b ).uniq.size == 4 } }
  return puts "Required tournament not possible!" unless second
  puts
  puts "Bang, bang, bang! Tournament is starting!"
  puts
  score = Players >> Players.size.times.map { 0 }
  [ first, second ].transpose.map { |a, b| [ a, b, Players - a - b ] }
    .each_with_index { |day, idx|
    puts
    puts "Day #{idx} is starting!"
    puts
    day.each { |pair| Bout.call *pair, score }
  }
  puts
  puts "Dam ti di dam! Tournament is over!"
  puts "Yusho goes to #{Players.max_by &score.method(:fetch)}. Congratulations!"
  puts
  puts "Full results:"
  score.pretty_print_numeric_values precision: 0
 end

def Go_fight! days
  Basho.call days: days
end

Go_fight! 5 #=> not possible
Go_fight! 3
```

You can see that you have asked a question which, in its literal form, has no solution. The above code uses brute force search to prove that your question has no solution for 5 tournament days and 4 tournament days, but is possible for 3 and less days.